# How to write Muḥammad ibn Mūsā al-Khwārizmī?

Tags: xetex, arabic

How can I write this name with LaTeX:

Also is the last letter an "l"?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: "Also is the last letter an 'l'?" No, it is an "i" whose dot is replaced with a macron (i.e. straight line above) ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find a font that has the glyph (Gentium, Linux Libertine, Times New Roman, Brill, etc.). The default Computer Modern version also works with `fontspec`.

Compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gentium}


\begin{document}

Muḥammad ibn Mūsā al-Khwārizmī?

Yes, Mu\d{h}ammad ibn M\={u}s\={a} al-Khw\={a}rizm\={\i}! 

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may be able to set up shortcuts in your editor if you're writing a lot of those diacritics.

If you want the same font as your example (Charis SIL):

```
\setmainfont{Charis Sil}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by ''The default Computer Modern version also works with fontspec''? I am compiling with xelatex and I am using the Latin Modern font but not using fontspec

Comment: why use ascii accent input, isn't it simpler just to use the text as in the question title?

Comment: @TertulianoMáximoAfonso, I mean, just compile with `xelatex` then. As David said, no need for special ascii input. I just used it as an example.

Comment: I quite like [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/) as a LaTeX Unicode font. It even comes with it's own `microtype` configuration!

Answer (score 7):

You didn't say what you had tried, but with xelatex, this works

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Muḥammad ibn Mūsā al-Khwārizmī

\end{document}
```

Comment: for pdflatex the same would work but you need to add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E25}{\d{h}}` in current releases.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
Mu\d{h}ammad ibn M\={u}s\={a} al-Khw\={a}rizm\={\i} 
\end{document}
```

The last letter is a dotless `i` (produce by `\i`) with bar above it.

Comment: you could use `\={\i}` or more simply `\={i}` but  `ī` is possibly simpler.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am old school... :-)

Answer (score 4):

`arabluatex` is also able to typeset Arabic proper names:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arabluatex}

\begin{document}

\SetTranslitConvention{dmg}
\prname{mu.hammad ibn mUs_A| al-_hwArizmiyy}

\SetTranslitConvention{arabica}
\prname{mu.hammad ibn mUs_A| al-_hwArizmiyy}

\SetTranslitConvention{loc}
\prname{mu.hammad ibn mUs_A| al-_hwArizmiyy}

\end{document}
```

[image]